# Windows Server 2003 User Login logger

Tags: windows-server-2003

This concerns my Computer Aided Engineering Drawing (CAED) lab.

There is a main server running Windows Server 2003 and clients running XP.
We students map a network drive to \\seg-fs[user] with username [user] and a common password for all students.

After completing our drafts in Solid Edge V19, we print the drafts at the server.
The lab asssistant navigates to [some-path]\[user]" in the explorer where all files of [user] are visible.

The problem is, some students copy others' files and sometimes also delete them.

My questions are:
Is there any way to know the users who log in to the server?
Is there any software to do so?

Comment: You would need to create separate user accounts for the students.  This would give you control over files and folders so no one could delete or access other student's work.  User accounts are easy to set up in Windows Server 2003...

Comment: That would involve creating more than 900 user accounts. Isn't there a way to log the accessed drives?

Comment: Well if everyone is logging in as the same user then you could only differentiate who logs in by computer.  But I think you don't have designated computers for each student, correct?

Comment: Only one user can map the same drive at any given time. And we can log in from any computer.

Comment: You could implement a system where each student inserts their student ID number into the filename when they save their file.  Then the admin of the server could set permissions on the folder where the files are stored so that the user account you all save log in as cannot delete or modify files.  Just save and read to the folder.  That might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you give all users the same user name and same permissions, you can log who deletes the file, but you don't know who the person is who is using that user name.

That is the whole purpose for different user accounts for every single user. It might be a farly large task to setup 900 new user accounts, but after that you can administer your network and file shares so you do not have students deleting or copying files that they shouldn't be.